# How do you read individual values from the same row in a database with sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am attempting to read 2 values from the same row in a database but I am only good enough to read the entire line at once. I have added all the code that I think will be relevant:

```
    def find(search, term):
        # Helper function for the find function.
        with connect("GTINb.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            sql = "select * from GTINb where {} = ?".format(search)
            cursor.execute(sql,(term,))
            db.commit()
            results = cursor.fetchall()
            new = str(term)
            if results:
                results = str(results)
                temp = open('temp.txt', 'a')
                temp.write(results)
                temp.write('\n')
                temp.close()
                with connect("GTINb.db") as db:
                    cursor.execute("UPDATE GTINb SET stockcur=stockcur-1 WHERE GTIN8=(?)",(new,))
                    cur = cursor.execute("SELECT stockcur from GTINb by (?)",(new,))
                    re = cursor.execute("SELECT restock from GTINb by (?)",(new,))
                    if cur < re:
                        cursor.execute("UPDATE GTINb SET stockcur=stockcur+10 WHERE GTIN8=(?)",(new,))
                        return print('More stock has been ordered in as stocks were low')
                    else:
                        return
            else:
                temp = open('temp.txt', 'a')
                temp.write('Product not found')
                temp.write('\n')
                temp.close()
                return
```

I am currently getting the error `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error`, and have tried replacing the '(?)' with %s, (%s) and ? with no success, coming up with the following error messages:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "12345670": syntax error // where 12345670 was the input represented by new
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error 
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

Is there another way of doing this or have I made a simple mistake?

Comment: What is `by (?)` supposed to mean? `by` can only be used as part of `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY`.

Comment: So it's treating `by` as the alias for the `GRINb` table, and it expects a `WHERE` clause (or some other clause) at that point in the SQL, but it finds `(?)`, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Barmar, by (?) is being used to refer to the known value in the row already which is the user input, and also the area which the mistake is probably in

Comment: `cursor.execute` doesn't return the column that you selected. You have to use a `fetch` operation to get the rows.

Comment: But that's not valid SQL syntax. It should be `WHERE somecolumn = ?`.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks, that was the problem that I had

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the SQL statements you've written are valid SQL. Please consult the [SQLite documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang.html) for the valid syntax.

Briefly:

```
 UPDATE GTINb SET stockcur=stockcur-1 WHERE GTIN8=(?)
 SELECT stockcur from GTINb by (?)
 SELECT restock from GTINb by (?)
```

should be

```
 UPDATE GTINb SET stockcur=stockcur-1 WHERE GTIN8 = ?
 SELECT stockcur FROM GTINb WHERE GTIN8 = ?
 SELECT restock FROM GTINb WHERE GTIN8 = ?
```

although the first one will probably execute with the unneeded parentheses.

Once you have your SQL working you will find that the second two statements can be combined into

```
 SELECT stockcur, restock  FROM GTINb WHERE GTIN8 = ?
```

which I believe is what you were asking about.

Comment: He also doesn't seem to know how to read the values returned correctly, you should add that to the answer.